# CSV Heat Map to Networkx Edge List

Tags: python, csv, networkx

I need to take a csv file like this one

```
,A,B,C  
B,0,0.25,1.3  
D,,,  
C,,0.75,1
```

Where A,B,C, and D are all nodes and the values are how strongly they are connected. As you can see, my input csv is not an adjacency matrix, nor are the nodes necessarily the same on each axis.

The idea is to convert the csv to a weighted edge list based on a threshold. For example, with a threshold of 0.3, the above csv would return:

```
C B 1.3  
B C 0.75  
C C 1
```

I'm fairly new to python and I have no idea how to go about doing this. I have been able to generate graphs from adjacency matrices, however, the data I am analyzing is no longer as clean and my code can no longer handle it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with

```
with open(my_csv_file) as f:
    s = f.read()
    lines = []
    row_headings = []
    edge_list = []
    for row, line in enumerate(s.split('\r\n')):
        lines.append(line)
        line_val = line.split(',')
        row_headings.append(line_val[0])
        col_headings = (lines[0].split(','))
        for col, val in enumerate(line.split(',')):
            try:
                if float(val) > threshold:
                    edge_list.append((col_headings[col], row_headings[row]))
            except ValueError:
                pass

DG = nx.DiGraph()        
my_graph = nx.from_edgelist(edge_list, create_using=DG)
```